# Sitecore 8.1 MIMEType font .woff issue

Tags: sitecore, mime-types, sitecore8.1, woff, woff2

We are using new fonts in application so I added following in MimeTypes.config file

```xml
<mediaType extensions=".woff"><mimeType>application/font-woff</mimeType></mediaType>
<mediaType extensions=".woff2"><mimeType>application/font-woff2</mimeType></mediaType>
```

but it's not working then I removed above and added following in web.config it's working properly.

```xml
<staticContent>
   <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
   <!-- In case IIS already has this mime type -->
   <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
   <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
   <!-- In case IIS already has this mime type -->
   <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
</staticContent>
```

But couldn't understand why it didn't work out when added in MimeTypes.config only which is specific to MIMEType configuration.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the mimetypes.config you define the extensions for Sitecore, but you also need to tell IIS what to do. That is what you are doing in the `staticContent` part.